# how can change the numeric to month in words

Tags: php, smarty

i need to try for the drop down with name of the month , the day and year in other loop,s

i try to conver the mm loop in string format,example the first month is jan and the value is 1

output will be below

```
   <option value=1>jan</option>
```

i use the following code

```
<select name="dd" id="dd">
<option value="">Day</option>
{for $foo=1 to 31}
 <option value="{$foo}">{$foo}</option>
{/for}
</select>
<select name="mm" id="mm">
<option value="">Month</option>
{for $foo=1 to 12}
 <option value="{$foo}">{$smarty.now|date_format:"%b"}</option>
{/for}
</select>
<select name="yy" id="yy">
<option value="">Year</option>
{for $foo=1970 to {$foo|date_format:"%Y"}}
 <option value="{$foo}">{$foo}</option>
{/for}
</select>
```

ple help me ..

Comment: The data value select the today .. but starting will be a string. like in day dropdown start with day   <option value="">Day</option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in [{html_select_date}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.select.date.tpl).

```
{html_select_date 
  start_year=1970 
  month_format="%b" 
  field_order="dmy" 
  field_array="date" 
  prefix="" 
  day_id="dd" 
  month_id="mm" 
  year_id="yy"
}
```

will generate HTML like

```
<select id="dd" name="date[Day]">
  <option value="1">01</option>
  …
  <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select id="mm" name="date[Month]">
  <option value="01">Jan</option>
  …
  <option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
<select id="yy" name="date[Year]">
  <option value="1970">1970</option>
  …
  <option selected="selected" value="2012">2012</option>
</select>
```

Hint: Set the `time="2011-05-17"` parameter to have that date selected.

Comment: The data value select the today .. but starting will be a string. like in day dropdown start with day <option value="">Day</option>

Comment: You can set those with the "empty" arguments: `year_empty="Year" month_empty="Month" day_empty="Day"`