# how can load the day in {html_select_date} from the day in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

i need to display the drop down when the day is come from mysql

my query is

```
select doj from user_detatils where user_id='2'
```

i use the html_select_date for the drop down option

The code is below

```
 {html_select_date start_year=1970 month_format="%b" field_order="dmy" 
  field_array="date" prefix="" day_id="dd" month_id="mm" year_id="yy" 
  year_empty="Year" month_empty="Month" day_empty="Day" }
```

if the table return the doj that date will be select in the drop down
else the drop down didn't select any value

Comment: how can select the drop down corresponding value from mysql

Comment: see if you can find an answer [here](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=31294&sid=386ed53d75b9882dfba0b45c3dba21b1) .. it's not hard to google you know.

Comment: {html_select_date start_year=1970 month_format="%b" field_order="dmy" 
  field_array="date" prefix="" day_id="dd" month_id="mm" year_id="yy" 
  year_empty="Year" month_empty="Month" day_empty="Day" time=$doj}                                                         is this possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on [how can change the numeric to month in words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190250/how-can-change-the-numeric-to-month-in-words/11191192#11191192).

[{html_select_date}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.select.date.tpl) explains the time argument. granted, it does a poor job in explaining that `time=null` will lead to "no date selected" and anything else that evaluates falsy (false, 0, "", …) will select the "current date".

So your PHP should check if the database has a valid date in doj, otherwise set that variable to `null`.

Comment: the table will return the value is 1985-05-27 then how can i load into {html_select_date}

Comment: `time="1985-05-27"`? the time parameter takes almost anything remotely looking like a date…

Comment: the date can be various value will return that time ho can i assign the value to {time} in {html_select_date} the user_id was change the date value also change that time how i assign the value ... like {html_select_date start_year=1970 month_format="%b" field_order="dmy" field_array="date" prefix="" day_id="dd" month_id="mm" year_id="yy" year_empty="Year" month_empty="Month" day_empty="Day" time=$doj}